# jquery do something at the begin and end of animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, client-side

I have the following JQuery code

```
        $("#classparent").click(function () {
            $(".classsubitems").slideToggle('slow', function () {
            });
        });
```

I need to let JQuery run some code at begin and end of animation.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple enough.

```
 $("#classparent").click(function () {         
    // before start of animation code here   
    $(".classsubitems").slideToggle('slow', function () {
        // end of animation code here in the callback
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

The code you want to execute before the animation you can place before the slideToggle method. The code you want to execute after the animation you can place in the callback function.

Answer (score 4):

SlideToggle has a callback-function (it looks like you already have provided that?)

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

For the code to be executed before the animation: the easies way to do this is simply calling it before the line with `$(".classsubitems")`.

Answer (score 1):

SlideToggle doesn't have callback method to call at the beggining but it is possible when completes.

```
  $("#classparent").click(function () {
             //Code to call before animation starts
             $(".classsubitems").slideToggle('slow', function () {    
               //code to execute after the animation finish.
         });         });
```